# Errors with a shell-script

Tags: bash, variables, global-variables

i found some freaky error. I want to increment a counter, but the variable isnt visible outside the while do.

The script as follows:

```
    ## $1 - The file which should be examined
## $2 - The time passed between the checks. If $2 is 5 then all lines from the last 5 minutes are taken
## $3 - The Errormessage to search for

outputOK="OK - nothing happened"
output_logcheck=0;
errlines="";

cat $1 | grep "$3" | while read line
do
        linedate=`date -d "$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 2)"  '+%s'`
        nowdate=`date '+%s'`

        if [ $(( $nowdate - (60 * $2) )) -le $linedate ]
        then
                $output_logcheck=$[$output_logcheck+1]
                $errlines="${errlines} -- ${line}"
        fi
done;

if [ $output_logcheck -eq 0 ]
then
        echo $outputOK
else
        echo "CRITICAL - There are -= ${output_logcheck} =- $3 -- Lines: $errlines"
fi
```

So i dont know what else to try. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a FAQ entry about this problem, just for future reference: ["I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pipe` create a `SubShell`.

change

```
cat $1 | grep "$3" | while read line
do
    ...
done
```

to

```
while read line
do
    ...
done <(cat $1 | grep "$3")
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the Bash shell, creates a subshell whenever a pipe is opened to a loop.  In that case, variables within the loop are local to the loop.

One kludge is to substitute (if possible) a Korn ('ksh') shell for the Bash one.

Comment: I'd argue that this is not a kludge, and is in fact one of the key strengths of ksh for shell programming

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
## $1 - The file which should be examined
## $2 - The time passed between the checks. If $2 is 5 then all lines from the last 5 minutes are taken
## $3 - The Errormessage to search for

outputOK="OK - nothing happened"
outfile="/tmp/result.$$"

trap { rm $outfile } 0 1 2 3

cat $1 | grep "$3" | (output_logcheck=0; errlines=""; while read line
do
        linedate=`date -d "$(echo $line | cut -d " " -f 2)"  '+%s'`
        nowdate=`date '+%s'`

        if [ $(( $nowdate - (60 * $2) )) -le $linedate ]
        then
                $output_logcheck=$[$output_logcheck+1]
                $errlines="${errlines} -- ${line}"
        fi
done; echo $output_logcheck ":" $errlines > $outfile)

output_logcheck=`cat $outfile| cut -f1 -d:`
errlines=`cat $outfile|cut -f2 -d:`

if [ $output_logcheck -eq 0 ]
then
        echo $outputOK
else
        echo "CRITICAL - There are -= ${output_logcheck} =- $3 -- Lines: $errlines"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`while` is executed in a separate process. Variables that are changed in the context of that process still hold their unchanged valus in the parent process.